# mvc4 connecting to MySQL database giving error

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a website build in mvc4. I am using mysql to connect to database.
When i tried to login, the login working fine, but after some page parsing, i am getting the error as:

```
"Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)"
```

My connection string is as:

```
 add name="DefaultConnection"
 connectionString="server=localhost;database='dbname';uid=username;pwd=password;persistsecurityinfo=True"
 providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient"
```

Please let me know what thin i need to change to make the website working.

Comment: What is "some page parsing"? Please show relevant code.

Comment: Means, after login, when i try to browse the pages, then i am getting this error. below is the code: Line 28:                 //  {
Line 29:                 //if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name,"Admin"))
Line 30:                     if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
Line 31:                     {
Line 32:                         <li>@Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", "Admin")</li>